# Disable "You should only open projects from a trustworthy source" message in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am opening the project from a network share and it keeps prompting me for this.  Anyone know how to stop the warning?

This is in Visual Studio 2015 blend.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7cf8f449-6f6c-42d4-bc41-ddf55142d8f1/how-to-disable-security-warning-you-should-only-open-projects-from-a-trustworthy-source?forum=vseditor

Comment: Covered at the [SE site](http://superuser.com/questions/44503/how-do-i-tell-windows-7-to-trust-a-particular-network-location) where you should ask questions like this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just uncheck the following option:

- *Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Warn user when project location is not trusted*

Comment: Thanks! This warning was really bugging me since I started using a Mac with Windows in a Parallels VM. As all the sources were on the Mac, Visual Studio asked me over and over again. So thank you!

Comment: Thank you.  This was really irritating me as we use a lot of network shares.

Comment: Works for VS2017 too.

Comment: Is there a way to make my project trustworthy? so that anyone who uses my application does not see any warning? without configuring anything in the visual studio..

Answer (score 15):

Rather than completely disabling the warning, you can remove the information that Windows uses to identify that the solution/project came from an untrustworthy source (but only for projects e.g. downloaded from the internet -- if you're opening them from a network location it considers non-trustworthy, such as a share that's not on Local Intranet, this doesn't apply). It stores this in an "Alternate Data Stream" (ADS) which you can view by running the following from the command prompt:

```
C:\devs\MyProject>dir /r
 Directory of C:\devs\MyProject

09/29/2016  03:43 PM    <DIR>          .
09/29/2016  03:43 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/29/2016  03:42 PM    <DIR>          API
09/29/2016  03:42 PM    <DIR>          bin
10/17/2016  10:32 AM             3,078 Project1.csproj
                                    26 Project1.csproj:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
```

The `Zone.Identifier:$DATA` ADS file is what's causing VS to identify it as untrusted. You can remove the data just for that project by right-clicking the `csproj` file, clicking Properties, and choosing "Unblock" on the General tab.

[image: Unblock in Explorer]

Or, to remove the ADS recursively for all files in a directory, download the [`streams` tool from SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/streams.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), cd to the directory and type:

```
streams -s -d .
```

Note that you can actually view the ADS file, which is just a regular text file, by typing e.g.

```
notepad Project1.csproj:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
```

In this case, it will have contents such as:

```
[ZoneTransfer]
ZoneId=3
```