# How does Visual Studio identify untrustworthy source

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded an open-source project from Github, as zip.

When i tried open it in VS, gave me "You should only open projects from a trustworthy source".

Question is - **how did VS identify that this project was downloaded, and was not authored by myself?**

Comment: Please have a look at this : https://superuser.com/questions/155953/vs-2010-security-warning-when-opening-my-own-projects it might be helpful

Comment: I think this answer has info about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089390/8212196

Comment: IE adds zone info (as Windows NTFS Alternative Data Streams) to download files